# Data in sharedpreference lost after apps exit

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am new in android. I am trying to save some information in sharedpreference which are getting from server. but when I exit the app, saved value in preference, setting 0. I want the values I saved in preference will stay same till I clear it manually.

Here is my code

```
public class SharedPreference {


        private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        static final String NAME = "RealTimeLocationTrackerUserId";
        static final String NAME_KEY = "name";
        static final String LOGIN_KEY = "login";


        public SharedPreference(Context context) {

            this.sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            this.editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        }

        public void save(String name) {

            editor.clear();

            editor.putBoolean(LOGIN_KEY, true);

            editor.putString(NAME_KEY, name);

            editor.commit();

        }

    public void remove() {

        editor.putBoolean(LOGIN_KEY, true);

        editor.clear();

        editor.commit();

    }

        public HashMap<String, String> retrieveData() {

            String name = sharedPreferences.getString(NAME_KEY, null);


            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(NAME_KEY, name);


            return map;
        }


    }
```

I am saving data from activity by calling:

```
sharedPreference.save(tmpOb.getString("user_id"));
```

and retrieving by:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = sharedPreference.retrieveData();
String loginName = map.get(SharedPreference.NAME_KEY);//testing
```

Comment: Why would you want to make your own class that contains SharedPreferences as a field? Why not just use default SharedPreference for saving the data?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to use Shared preference just call this method

Use this class for store and retrieve Sharepreference in your project just copy an pest this class

**SharedPreferenceManager.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class SharedPreferenceManager  {

    public static void setDefaults(String key, String value, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putString(key, value);

        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getDefaults(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }


    public static void setDefaults_boolean(String key, boolean value, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static Boolean getDefaults_boolean(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, Boolean.parseBoolean(null));
    }

    public static void ClearAllPreferences(Context context){

        //remove all your prefs
        context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0).edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

For Store value

```
SharedPreferenceManager.setsetDefaults("key","Value",context);
```

For retrieve value

```
SharedPreferenceManager.getDefaults("Key",Context);
```

Comment: thank you but in my case this is not working.the id i get from server and saved it is showing 0 after app exit.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this library](https://github.com/viralypatel/Android-SharedPreferences-Helper), which simplifies the use of `SharedPreferences` and will make life simpler for you.

> **Android-SharedPreferences-Helper** simplifies usage of the default Android SharedPreferences Class. The developer can do in a few lines
>   of code which otherwise would have required several. Simple to
>   understand as compared to the default class and easy to use.
>
> - One line initialization and setup
> - Easily selecting whether to use default preferences or a custom preference file
> - Predefined (data type defaults) and customizable (what you may choose) default values for each datatype
> - Ability to set different default value for single use with just an additional param
> - You can register and unregister OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener as you do for default class